# Take an automnatic screenshot of the screen when the map finises loading

Tags: android, screenshot, openstreetmap

I am creating a app which displays the current location of the user in the map. I am using OpenStreetMap. This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private LocationManager locationManager;
private Location onlyOneLocation;
private final int REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION = 1234;
public GeoPoint startPoint;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Context ctx = getApplicationContext();

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_FINE_LOCATION);

    //important! set your user agent to prevent getting banned from the osm servers
    Configuration.getInstance().load(ctx, PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ctx));
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final MapView map = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
    map.setTileSource(TileSourceFactory.MAPNIK);
    map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    map.setMultiTouchControls(true);

    final IMapController mapController = map.getController();
    mapController.setZoom(18);

    CurrentLocation.requestSingleUpdate(this,
            new CurrentLocation.LocationCallback() {

                @Override public void onNewLocationAvailable(GPSCoordinates location) {
                    Log.d("Location", "my location is " + location.latitude + " : " + location.longitude);
                    startPoint = new GeoPoint(location.latitude, location.longitude);

                    // My Location Overlay
                    Marker marker=new Marker(map);
                    marker.setPosition(startPoint);
                    marker.setTitle("Your Location");
                    marker.showInfoWindow();
                    map.getOverlays().add(marker);
                    map.invalidate();
                    //This geopoint is currently static and shows a single location everytime the app is executed
                    mapController.setCenter(startPoint);

                    takeScreenshot();
                }
            });}

private void takeScreenshot() {

    HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("content_observer");
    handlerThread.start();
    final Handler handler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper())
    {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg)
        {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    };

    getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            true,
            new ContentObserver(handler)
            {
                @Override
                public boolean deliverSelfNotifications()
                {

                    return super.deliverSelfNotifications();
                }

                @Override
                public void onChange(boolean selfChange)
                {
                    super.onChange(selfChange);
                }

                @Override
                public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri)
                {


                    String screen_shot = "1";

                    if (uri.toString().matches(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString() + "/[0-9]+"))
                    {

                        Cursor cursor = null;
                        try
                        {
                            cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]
                                    {
                                            MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                                            MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
                                    }, null, null, null);

                            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
                            {
                                final String fileName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                                final String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));



                            }
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            if (cursor != null)
                            {
                                cursor.close();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    super.onChange(selfChange, uri);
                }
            }
    );
}
```

}

When the map finishes loading with the user current location, I want to take an automatic screenshot of that screen for further use. I added a code to take the screenshot but I am not able to achieve the same. What changes should I make?

Comment: what was the issue?

Comment: There is no error but I am not able to see the screen shot, so i am not able to understand that the screen shot is successfully take or not

Comment: have you taken permission for access storage?

Comment: Yes i have taken this permission  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" /> and  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: i mean run time permission for android version 6 and above also add the  e.printStackTrace(); log for more details

Comment: No i have not added that yet

Comment: try that as you did for ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just simple use the code for taking screenshot

```
 HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("content_observer");
    handlerThread.start();
    final Handler handler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper())
    {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg)
        {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    };

    getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            true,
            new ContentObserver(handler)
            {
                @Override
                public boolean deliverSelfNotifications()
                {

                    return super.deliverSelfNotifications();
                }

                @Override
                public void onChange(boolean selfChange)
                {
                    super.onChange(selfChange);
                }

                @Override
                public void onChange(boolean selfChange, Uri uri)
                {


                    screen_shot = "1";

                    if (uri.toString().matches(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI.toString() + "/[0-9]+"))
                    {

                        Cursor cursor = null;
                        try
                        {
                            cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, new String[]
                                    {
                                    MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                                    MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA
                            }, null, null, null);

                            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
                            {
                                final String fileName = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME));
                                final String path = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA));



                            }
                        }
                        finally
                        {
                            if (cursor != null)
                            {
                                cursor.close();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    super.onChange(selfChange, uri);
                }
            }
    );
```

Comment: Where should I add this part of the code in my code given above?

Comment: @Thomas  Just replace your "takeScreenshot" method code with above one

Comment: @Thomas Can you please post your new code which one your replaced

Comment: I posted the updated code. i replaced the part of the code you told

Answer (score 1):

Have you add following permission in your code.And add Dangerous/Runtime permission for API level 23 and above if you are using

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

Comment: Yes I have added these also

Comment: @Thomas don't know Thomas what mistake you have done. It's working fine in my code. I tested it personally

Comment: Can you post pat of the code where you tested it so that I can see what mistake I have done

Comment: @Thomas provide me your mail id?

Comment: Did you get my id?

Comment: @Thomas yes check your mail

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153864/discussion-between-thomas-and-yash786).